# Prove that $\exists$ a subfield of a particular degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Q) Let $E$ be a normal extension of $F$ with $[E:F] = 80$. Prove that $\exists$ a subextension $G\subset E$ s.t. $[G:F] = 5$.

Since $E$ is a normal extension, it is a splitting field of $F$. My first question is if $|Gal(E/F)| = [E:F]$ true for all $F$ or for $F$ of characteristic = $0$ like $\mathbb{Q}$? Assuming $|Gal(E/F)| = [E:F] = 80$, if $Gal(E/F)$ is a cyclic group, I know that it has a unique subgroup of order $16$ as $16|80$. Thus by Galois correspondence, $\exists$ a subextension $G$ of $E$ s.t. $[G:F] = 5$. So the second question is about proving the group is cyclic or getting the result otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't assume the extension is separable.  Even if the extension is separable, there is no reason why the Galois group is cyclic.

Comment: I see, forgot that if the extension is separable then $|Gal(E/F) = [E:F]$. May I know how to approach the problem otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: When the extension is separable and the group is not cyclic, you can still find a subgroup of order $16$ (and thus of index $5$) by taking a $2$-Sylow. So the separable case works without any cyclicity assumption

Comment: I see, thanks, I'm not given separability of the extension but for the second part, since $80=2^4\times 5$, the Sylow-2 subgroup is of order 16?